# Anaconda Environment Has All System Packages Installed By Default

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I wanted to create a conda environment to work on a Django Web App. 
I checked if the environment had existed before:

```
    conda activate django_movie_app
    Could not find conda environment: django_movie_app
    You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

Then I created my environment using:

```
    conda create --name django_movie_app
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: done
```

However after I activated the environment using

```
`conda activate django_movie_app`
```

I checked pip freeze and all system packages were installed

```
    pip freeze
    alabaster==0.7.12
    anaconda-client==1.7.2
    anaconda-navigator==1.9.12
    anaconda-project==0.8.3
    argh==0.26.2
    asgiref==3.2.4
    asn1crypto==1.3.0
    astroid==2.3.3
    astropy==4.0.1.post1
    atomicwrites==1.4.0
    attrs==19.3.0
    autopep8==1.5
    Babel==2.8.0
    backcall==0.1.0
    backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.1
    backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
    backports.tempfile==1.0
    backports.weakref==1.0.post1
    bcrypt==3.1.7
    beautifulsoup4==4.9.0
    bitarray==1.2.1
    bkcharts==0.2
    bleach==3.1.4
    bokeh==1.4.0
    boto==2.49.0
    Bottleneck==1.3.2 etc
```

Running conda info returned the environment was active:

```
    conda info

              active environment : django_movie_app
```

I have tried reinstalling the environments after deleting them from the explorer (They were not available afterwards --> See above) and I still had the same problem afterwards.

I have created normal environments before where this was not a problem. However, now conda keeps installing all packages and some older versions cannot be uninstalled using `pip uninstall`.

Comment: I'd first make sure that you are using the right pip. Do you get the same result if you do `python -m pip list` after activating the environment? Then I would make sure that you do not have `PYTHONPATH` set - check e.g. `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" for paths to other python interpreters.

Comment: In the future, please be sure to explicitly ask a question (currently, there is none). If you only created the env and didn't install any Python or `pip`, then that `pip` is not referring to the environment (check `which pip`). Consider keeping your (PYTHON)PATH clean of system-level Python (and `pip`) installations, such as what you are seeing - leakage into what should be isolated environments can be problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the commands you listed above, you haven't actually installed anything to the `django_movie_app` environment yet, so when you call `pip`, your shell is finding some other version of `pip` that happens to exist on your `PATH` -- not one from the `django_movie_app` environment.  (It looks like your conda `base` environment is still on your `PATH` somewhere.  That's not necessarily a problem, as long as `django_movie_app/bin`.)

Does everything work as expected if you try the following commands?

```
conda create -n django_movie_app
conda activate django_movie_app
conda install python=3.7
pip freeze
```

BTW, the conda command to list your current environment's installed packages is:

```
conda list
```

...which gives a little more info than `pip freeze`.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create --name py37 python=3.7 
conda activate py37
```

Check the [Conda Cheat sheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) for more understanding and to see multiple commands with their description.